# Progress Bar showing the duration as a percentage of time passed over a period of time

Tags: ios, swift

I need an algorithm in Swift 3, that will calculate a percentage of time passed over it's period.
I will try to show this on example, because it is hard to explain with words.

Let's say we have:

Start time - 16:00
and End Time - 18:00.

If current time is 17:30 the progress bar should show 75%

[Example Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAKRj.png)

Comment: 18.00 - 16.00 = 100%,  so 18.00 - 17.30 = 75%

Comment: It's simple math: The time difference in minutes is 100%. In your example 120 min are 100%, 90 min are 75%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your three times to NSTimeIntervals from 1970, then (current - start) / (end - start)

Comment: ok thank you for the algorithm, but now how I Implement it in swift 3 ?

Comment: @xbomber360 it's really wide question, we don't know Your case, and **exact** usage. There's no source code or anything we can base on.

Comment: ok I will find more on official swift documentation. thank you

Comment: Why 1970? Whats front with saving the start date and just getting the timeIntervalSinceNow (past start date the result will be negative) or Date().timeIntervalSince(startDate)  (past start date the result will be positive)

Comment: You could certainly use "now," but even if you're OK with now being a slightly moving target, you've got to do a conversion to time interval anyway, and 1970 makes debugging a bit easier on the eyes with no negative intervals.

Answer (score 0):

This is a (very) quick mockup I wrote on Playground.

```
import UIKit

let ms1: Double = 1490000000
let ms2: Double = 1560000000

let date1: Date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: ms1)
let date2: Date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: ms2)
let now: Date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)

let percentage = (now.timeIntervalSince1970 - date1.timeIntervalSince1970) * 100 / (date2.timeIntervalSince1970 - date1.timeIntervalSince1970)
```

[image: And it looks something like this]